# Android HorizontalScrollView with right layout_gravity working wrong

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I'm trying to get following view: Description on left site and value on the right. e.g.:

[image]

The problem is that the text can be long so I wrap it in HorizontalScrollView. I'm using following xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:text="Description:"/>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Very1 very2 very3 very4 very5 very6 long text"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the problem. After scroling to left most corner I got view (**missing beginning of text**):

[image]

After scroling to right most corner I got view (**addition space after text**):

[image]

If I change the TextView android:layout_gravity to "left" everything works as expected. After scroling to left most corner I got view:

[image]

After scroling to right most corner I got view:

[image]

Is it a way to make it working correctly and align text to right site when it is short?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while but here is a workaround (tested):

```
public class RightAlignedHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
private boolean mGravityRight = false;
private boolean mAutoScrolling = false;

public RightAlignedHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RightAlignedHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RightAlignedHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public View getChildView() {
    return getChildAt(0);
}

private int getScrollRange() {
    int scrollRange = 0;
    if (getChildCount() > 0) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        scrollRange = Math.max(0, child.getWidth() - (getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()));
    }
    return scrollRange;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    // HorizontalScrollView is broken for Gravity.RIGHT. So we're fixing it.
    mAutoScrolling = false;
    int childWidth = getChildView().getWidth();
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    int delta = getChildView().getWidth() - childWidth;
    View childView = getChildView();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) childView.getLayoutParams();
    int horizontalGravity = p.gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
    int verticalGravity = p.gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
    if (horizontalGravity == Gravity.RIGHT) {
        if (getScrollRange() > 0) {
            mGravityRight = true;
            p.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | verticalGravity;
            childView.setLayoutParams(p);
            super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    } else if (mGravityRight) {
        if (getScrollRange() == 0) {
            mGravityRight = false;
            p.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | verticalGravity;
            childView.setLayoutParams(p);
            super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    }
    if (mGravityRight && delta > 0) {
        scrollBy(delta, 0);
        mAutoScrolling = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if (mAutoScrolling) return;
    super.computeScroll();
}

@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    if (mAutoScrolling) return;
    super.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Don't use any layout gravity for TextView, it will work as you expected only.

As you told, problem is there, its behaving wrongly with right gravity.

Comment: But I want the text to be on the right, if it is short (see first image).
If I remove gravity - the behavior is exactly as with gravity set to left. The question is: how to make it right align or scrollable, depending on text length.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been inactive for a year, but it's still a problem in 2013. Create a new class that extends HorizontalScrollView and copy / paste the code below.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    autoScrolling = false;
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

private int getScrollRange() {
    int scrollRange = 0;
    if(getChildCount() > 0) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        scrollRange = Math.max(0, child.getWidth() - (getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()));
    }
    return scrollRange;
}

private boolean gravityRight = false;
private boolean autoScrolling = false;

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    // HorizontalScrollView is broken for Gravity.RIGHT. So we're fixing it.
    if(getChildCount() == 0) return super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    int childWidth = getChildAt(0).getWidth();
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    int delta = getChildAt(0).getWidth() - childWidth;
    AdvancedDisplay view = getView();
    ScrollableDisplay.LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    int horizontalGravity = p.gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
    int verticalGravity = p.gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
    if(horizontalGravity == Gravity.RIGHT) {
        if(getScrollRange() > 0) {
            gravityRight = true;
            p.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | verticalGravity;
            view.setLayoutParams(p);
            super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    }
    else if(gravityRight) {
        if(getScrollRange() == 0) {
            gravityRight = false;
            p.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | verticalGravity;
            view.setLayoutParams(p);
            super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    }
    if(gravityRight && delta > 0) {
        autoScrolling = false;
        scrollBy(delta, 0);
        autoScrolling = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if(autoScrolling) return;
    super.computeScroll();
}

@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    if(autoScrolling) return;
    super.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in your child layout

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

That should be working (for me it is)
Hope it helps